# How to exchange a heavy box of mixed-denomination coins?

Tags: united-kingdom, cash, coins

I'm living in the UK and I'm about to move flat. In the five years in my current flat I've accumulated around 20kg of mixed coins - from £0.05 to €2 at a glance. Are there any easy ways to exchange this with a bank or other institution/individual for some reasonable approximation of its worth?

Comment: did you ask your local bank?

Comment: Do you have a specific objection to coinstar?  Excessive fee? http://www.coinstar.co.uk

Comment: I did end up using a coinstar at my local Tesco! The fee wasn't too excessive, I got around £0.92 for every £1.00 I put in.